# How can I change the default bash look?

Tags: bash

My bash is white and black and I would like it to look much more colorful, how do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Terminal -> Preferences -> Settings

[image]

Select a color scheme and click `Default`

Comment: And [Solarized](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) is a nice color scheme for Terminal and many other programs.

Answer (score 1):

In the settings mentioned in earlier answers you can only change the main background and foreground colors, but if you want to for instance change the prompt, you have to set the PS1 env variable.

There are many examples that can be found with some googling, I use this (username in blue, path in green) for my black background:

```
PS1="\[\e[36;1m\]\u:\[\e[32;1m\]\w$ \[\e[0m\]"
```

Add that piece of code to a file called `.bash_profile` in your home directory (it's hidden, or most likely don't exist if you haven't used it for anything yet). You may also just enter the code in the terminal once to preview it.

Edit: [More info here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/bash-shell-ps1-10-examples-to-make-your-linux-prompt-like-angelina-jolie/), Works in OS X even though they write about Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the Terminal Preferences dialog, Settings pane.